# LWJGL Player Health bar not positioning properly

Tags: java, opengl, position, lwjgl

I'm making a game in Java using LWJGL and slick_util recently I'm trying to implement a health bar that will hover on top of the player's head. Problem is, it is not positioning correctly. The health bar's bottom left corner(from where OpenGL starts drawing) always appears at the top right corner of the player's rectangle, and when the player moves in either x or y or both, the health bar moves away from the player in the same direction. I think it might be a problem with the glTranslatef or perhaps something silly that I missed.

Render method of Player:

```
protected void render() {
        Draw.rect(x, y, 32, 32, tex); //Player texture drawn
        Draw.rect(x, y + 33, 32, 15, 1, 0, 0); //Health bar drawn. x is the same as player's, but y is +33 because I want it to hover on top
    }
```

Draw class:

```
package rpgmain;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Samsung
 */
public class Draw {

    public static void rect(float x, float y, float width, float height, Texture tex) {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);        
        glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        tex.bind();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Specifies to the program where the drawing code begins. just to keep stuff neat. GL_QUADS specifies the type of shape you're going to be drawing.
        {
            //PNG format for images
            glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(0, 0);  //Specify the vertices. 0, 0 is on BOTTOM LEFT CORNER OF SCREEN.
            glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0, height); //2f specifies the number of args we're taking(2) and the type (float)
            glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(width, height); 
            glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(width, 0);
        }
        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    public static void rect(float x, float y, float width, float height, float r, float g, float b) {
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        glColor3f(r, g, b); 

        glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Specifies to the program where the drawing code begins. just to keep stuff neat. GL_QUADS specifies the type of shape you're going to be drawing.
        {                 
            glVertex2f(0, 0);  //Specify the vertices. 0, 0 is on BOTTOM LEFT CORNER OF SCREEN.
            glVertex2f(0, height); //2f specifies the number of args we're taking(2) and the type (float)
            glVertex2f(width, height);
            glVertex2f(width, 0); 
        }
        glEnd();
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with matrices. When you call glTranslatef, you are transforming the OpenGL ModelView matrix. However, since OpenGL is a state-based machine, this transformation is preserved for further drawing events. The second rectangle will be translated twice. What you want to do is use the OpenGL matrix stack. I'll rewrite one of the draw methods here:

```
public static void rect(float x, float y, float width, float height, Texture tex) {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);        
    glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    tex.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0, height);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(width, height); 
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(width, 0);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

The line glPushMatrix() will add a new matrix to the top of the stack. All transformations from this point on will be applied to the newly added matrix. Then, when you call glPopMatrix(), the matrix is discarded and the stack is returned to it's previous state.

Comment: :D Worked like a charm. Though it works, I still want to understand one thing. When I call the render method from my Game class, which runs through every GameObject and updates and renders it, I put glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix there as well and between them the render calls for the particular GameObject. By adding the additional Push and Pops in the Draw method, am I adding a new matrix to an already present parent matrix? Or am I just adding a new element to the main matrix? Thanks in advance - Rex

Comment: Basically, glPushMatrix() saves the current state of the OpenGL matrix to the top of a stack. The current matrix will be unaffected, except that a call to glLoadIdentity() would restore the matrix to it's state when glPushMatrix() was last called. Any transformations are applied to that matrix. When glPopMatrix() is called, a matrix is "popped" off the top of the stack, and becomes the current matrix. The matrix is then restored to it's state the last time glPopMatrix() was called. An additional call to glPopMatrix() would go up one more level.